# How work with laravel passport and flutter

Tags: laravel, flutter, dart, laravel-passport

I'm new to flutter. I have some experience in laravel. I need to make a login/register flow in flutter with laravel passport password grant. What's a good way to do this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 1):

In laravel project>composer require laravel/passport. Download the packages:

```
 php artisan migrate
 php artisan passport:install
```